# Можно ли теги DIV заворачивать в SPAN?

Tags: html, faq

Можно ли блочные элементы помещать внутрь строчных?

```
<span><div></div><div></div></span>
```

такой код корректен?

Comment: Возникает только вопрос: зачем? Вспоминается притча о троллейбусе из буханки хлеба

Answer (score 5):

нет, это не валидно, лучше написать наоборот

```
<div><span></span><span></span></div>
```

Comment: а `<div style="display: inline"><div></div></div>` правильно? а `<span style="dislplay: block"><div></div></span>`?

Comment: 1 вариант, но лучше используйте css стили. Внутри span использовать div не надо

Comment: Непонятно какое-то правило получается. Логично было бы предположить, что строчный элемент может содержаться в блочном, но не наоборот. Но если обычно блочному элементу подменить стиль на строчный и это остаётся правильным, то почему бы сразу не помещать в изначально строчный элемент?

Comment: тег span создан для оформления текста, это не блок, как div

Comment: Вложить можна, но тогда тяжело добится кроссбраузерности. Редакторы ругаются warning-ом на такое вложение.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно WHATWG внутри элемента `span` можно вставлять phrasing content.

> Источник: [Semantics of span element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-span-element), [phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2)

Если опустить семантику, то вставлять внутрь спана можно что угодно, главное позаботиться о том, чтобы он был блочным, т. е. добавить ему в стилях `display: block`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Нет, такое вложение не является валидным.
2. Все браузеры обработают его корректно и проблем не будет.
3. Стоит позаботится о корректных значениях свойства `display`.